# Best way to transfer an xml to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have been hearing the podcast blog for a while, I hope I dont break this. 
The question is this: I have to insert an xml to a database. This will be for already defined tables and fields. So what is the best way to accomplish this? So far I am leaning toward programatic. I have been seeing varios options, one is Data Transfer Objects (DTO), in the SQL Server there is the sp_xml_preparedocument that is used to get transfer XMLs to an object and throught code.

I am using CSharp and SQL Server 2005. The fields are not XML fields, they are the usual SQL datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

In an attempt to try and help, we may need some clarification. Maybe by restating the problem you can let us know if this is what you're asking:

**How can one import existing xml into a SQL 2005 database, without relying on the built-in xml type?**

A fairly straight forward solution that you already mentioned is the *sp_xml_preparedocument*, combined with *openxml*.

Hopefully the following example illustrates the correct usage. For a more complete example checkout the MSDN docs on [Using OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187897(SQL.90).aspx).

```
declare @XmlDocumentHandle int
declare @XmlDocument nvarchar(1000)
set @XmlDocument = N'<ROOT>
<Customer>
   <FirstName>Will</FirstName>
   <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Customer>
</ROOT>'

-- Create temp table to insert data into
create table #Customer 
( 
    FirstName varchar(20),
    LastName varchar(20) 
)
-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlDocumentHandle output, @XmlDocument

-- Insert using openxml allows us to read the structure
insert into #Customer
select 
    FirstName = XmlFirstName,
    LastName = XmlLastName
from openxml ( @XmlDocumentHandle, '/ROOT/Customer',2 )
with 
(
    XmlFirstName  varchar(20) 'FirstName',
    XmlLastName varchar(20) 'LastName'
)
where ( XmlFirstName = 'Will' and XmlLastName = 'Smith' )

-- Cleanup xml document
exec sp_xml_removedocument @XmlDocumentHandle

-- Show the data
select * 
from #Customer

-- Drop tmp table
drop table #Customer
```

If you have an xml file and are using C#, then defining a stored procedure that does something like the above and then passing the entire xml file contents to the stored procedure as a *string* should give you a fairly straight forward way of importing xml into your existing table(s).

Answer (score 0):

If your XML conforms to a particular XSD schema, you can look into using the "xsd.exe" command line tool to generate C# object classes that you can bind the XML to, and then form your insert statements using the properties of those objects: [MSDN XSD Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Peruse this document and it will give you the options:

MSDN: [XML Options in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345110(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use XSLT to transfer your XML into SQL statements... ie

```
<xml type="user">
    <data>1</data>
    <data>2</data>
<xml>
```

Then the XSLT would look like

```
<xsl:template match="xml">
    INSERT INTO <xsl:value-of select="@type" /> (data1, data2) VALUES (
       '<xsl:value-of select="data[1]" />',
       '<xsl:value-of select="data[2]" />');
</xsl:template>
```

The match statement most likely won't be the root node, but hopefully you get the idea. You may also need to wrap the non xsl:value-of parts in xsl:text to prevent extra characters from being dumped into the query. And you'd have to make sure the output of the XSLT was text. That said you could get a list of SQL statements that you could run through the DB. or you could use XSLT to output a T-SQL statement that you could load as a stored procedure.